# Permanent Views Pages

Tags: 7, views, nodes

Something I've been battling for some time: Is there any way to make the results of a views page permanent?

For Instance: There is a club racing website that inputs Entrants as nodes, to events, which are also nodes. The entrants get scores based upon their performance at the event. However, Entrants come and go in the club, and as they come and go so should their nodes.

Is there any way to make their scores still appear on a views page, even if I happen to delete or unpublish their node? Is there a, 'print as static' option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The views module actively queries (and caches) a database table for results; trying to make the results static or somehow retrieving deleted content would be much work fighting against views' design. I'd say if you're already using unpublishing to designate former entrants, you're better off using the [View Unpublished](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_unpublished) module to give roles the ability to see unpublished entrants.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I don't know if that is exactly what I am looking for, because anonymous users will most likely be viewing these event result pages, and wouldn't be restricted to roles. However, your answer did lead me to a workable conclusion:  Simply change the view to show published AND not-published nodes, so that I may unpublish any racers whom are no longer with the club.

Comment: So testing this has indeed, come down to using the View Unpublished module, because by default, a anonymous user is unable to see unpublished content. Thank you again for you insight :)